# Angular material - Mat Form Field

Tags: angular, angular-material

When providing default mat-form-field options:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...modules],
  exports: [...modules],
  providers: [{
    provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'fill' }
  }],
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

It also changes the look of the paginator select page input to filled appearance.

Is there any way that I can keep the look of the default paginator select input ?

Comment: i know it takes some effort depending on how many form field inputs you have but setting appearance="fill" on each input could be a working workaround.

Comment: If you have separate "TableComponent" you can add a provider at that component's level without the fill. This way, all fields in that component (and children components) will not use fill, while the rest of the module will. The way DI work, it traverses the tree of components and looks for the first available provider, up to to the module level.